# Ajax. How can I return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, ajax

I want set result to variable from MVC controller method.

```
function someFunction(){ 
    var result;
    $.Ajax{    
        //??? 
    }
    return result; 
}
```

//In comparison to c++

```
int f() { //just! return result; }
```

P.S.: It is not async, it should be sync function call in order to return value to the function body.

Comment: Did you read the jQuery documentation?  It's full of examples.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: JavaScript is [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture). You make the Ajax-call and assign a callback function which is called when the response comes in.

Comment: I know about this page. But I have simple question. And I want pretty simple answer. In c++ it's just one string. What about jQuery?

Comment: Simple answer is ... You can't .... can can perform a function on success but not return a value

Comment: @Anton **if** you had put the correct relavent information into your question at the very beginning you would have saved a lot of time / wrong answers ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set up a controller

```
public ActionResult Foo(){

return Content("Hello Anton");
}
```

set up the ajax request, remember to make it `async:false`, which is by default true, in order to return the value

```
function greeting(){
   var x= $.ajax({
            url:'/ControllerName/Foo',
            async:false,    
          });
   return x.responseText();
}
```

now you can call the function like

```
var v = greeting();
alert(v); //if every thing goes well you will see "Hello Anton"
```

Comment: It seems to me that it's the right answer. I'll check it. Wait a sec please. :)

Comment: @3nigma I think you have to remove the comma after **False**

Comment: @Anwar that would not make any difference, but watch out for IE `:)`

Comment: @3nigma yes I usually use IE. Anyway I learned today that Ajax calls can work in synchronously and it can return values. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call works asynchronously and it works like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/{Your Controller Name}/{Action Name}',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('My returned data is:' + data);
  }
});
```

After your Ajax request is successfully processed you can process you're returned
data in the success event.

**Edit:**
I've experimented 3nigma's Answer and it worked as Anton requested.

Comment: I know about alert. I don't need alert, I need return variable value into function body and do some logic after.

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction(){
    var result;
    $.Ajax({
        url: '/some/ajax/call',
        success: function (data){
            result = data;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

See the section about success: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This will not work .... you will get an error `result undefined` as the AJAX is asynchronous

Comment: This doesn't work, you return the result before it is set to data becaune the function Ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: This won't actually work - result will return before the ajax call finishes (that is, before `result=data;` happens), so result will most likely come back as 'undefined'.

Comment: So I see - well, my bad on that. The accepted answer with async: false is "where it's at."

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on returning the result, because, as mentioned by Anwar, ajax is asynchronous. What you have to do is define a callback function that does something with the result once it does come back, in this case the 'success' function.

Comment: Yep! It's much closer to the answer. It is not async, it should be sync in order to return value.

Comment: Look at setting `async: false` in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result;

function someFunction(){
    var result;
    $.Ajax({
        url: '/some/ajax/call',
        success: function (data){
            result = data;
            // call a method that processes result
        }
    });
}
```

You could do this ... `result` is created before the function is called - upon successfully return of data by the AJAX call the success method assigns `data` to `result` you could call a function after result is updated - to do something else